# Django combobox from objects of another model

Tags: python, django, combobox

I would like to do something like : I have one model names for example
model A -> `class A(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 50)`

than i would like to have model B -> where i create variable which will be combobox from model A objects , is there a way to do it in django ? I've tried something like : `ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyOtherModel.objects.all(), to_field_name="column_with_the_value')` but always says that my model A has no attribute objects .

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Django Form [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/) for how to 'display' the form, if that is what you are looking for. Or, you could pass some [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) to the model field, like so:

```
value = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=((50,50), (40,40))
```